# Issue of Reading and Converting Date of Google Calendar Events when language is set to Arabic in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, google-calendar-api, datetime-format, google-api-dotnet-client

I am Using Google APis .net client library to read calendar events.

I have following line of code

```
newRow["Start"] = pEventItem.Start.DateTime.HasValue ? 
Convert.ToDateTime(pEventItem.Start.DateTime) : Convert.ToDateTime(pEventItem.Start.Date);
```

Where PEventItem is of type Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event and NewRow[...] is of type DataRow. The Value of pEventItem.Start.Date is "2019-06-24"  (as seen in debug window)

The above line of code works perfect, **But fails** when UI language / Culture is set to Arabic (SaudiArabia) The same Convert.ToDateTime throws error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

btw, How i am changing the UI language is as below for your information.

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(ChangeLanguageTo);
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(ChangeLanguageTo);
```

I tried to set 2nd parameter of the Convert.ToDateTime function in an hope that it will convert date correctly...

```
CultureInfo enUsCulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
newRow["Start"] = pEventItem.Start.DateTime.HasValue ? Convert.ToDateTime(pEventItem.Start.DateTime, enUsCulture) : Convert.ToDateTime(pEventItem.Start.Date, enUsCulture);
```

Well Now it does not throw exception, but the returned date is incorrect. value retuned is {21/10/40 12:00:00 ص}

while The actual date pEventItem.Start.Date is "2019-06-24"

I also tried invariant culture also, but result is same, converted date is wrong.  What could be the issue?

Regards

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things going on here.

Firstly, if you use `EventDateTime.DateTime` (e.g. via `pEventItem.Start.DateTime`) you don't need to call `Convert.ToDateTime`, because that's already a `DateTime?`... you can just take the `Value` property to get a `DateTime` from a `DateTime?`. However, I should warn that that can perform time zone conversions that you may not want. (We can't fix the library to avoid those, as it would be a breaking change.) Instead, you may want to parse `EventDateTime.DateTimeRaw`, which is the original string value returned by the API.

When parsing, I'd suggest using the invariant culture using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` (instead of creating an en-US culture), and parse using `DateTime.ParseExact`, specifying the format you expect based on whether you're parsing a date or a full date/time.

In terms of "the returned date is incorrect" - I believe that's really just the formatted value that's using the default culture, *including the calendar system*. We can see that at play in the code below, which constructs the `DateTime` directly (so can't be affected by any text parsing etc). When formatted using the invariant culture, it shows as 2019-06-24, but when formatted with ar-SA, it shows as "1440-10-21" due to the default calendar system for that culture being `System.Globalization.UmAlQuraCalendar`:

```cs
// Note: when a calendar system is not specified,
// it's implicitly Gregorian.
DateTime date = new DateTime(2019, 6, 24);

Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", new CultureInfo("ar-SA")));
```

So what you're seeing in the debugger is the correct date - but formatted in a way you weren't expecting.

Comment: pEventItem.Start.DateTimeRaw returns null;

Comment: newRow["Start"] = pEventItem.Start.DateTime.HasValue ? Convert.ToDateTime(pEventItem.Start.DateTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : Convert.ToDateTime(pEventItem.Start.Date, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  return same result as "en-us"   example:  {21/10/40 12:00:00 ص}

Comment: OMG, I tried to put this statement in debug window  :   DateTime.ParseExact(pEventItem.Start.Date,"yyyy-MM-dd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)  and it too returned {21/10/40 12:00:00 ص}       Now i am not sure why this is happening :(

Comment: I didn;t notice this earlier, but watch window shows ,  It looks like pEventItem.Start.Date is of "String" type.   and i wonder why pEventItem.Start.DateTime is null  but pEventItem.Start.Date has a value ?     Google Library is confusing.

Comment: @Neha: The `DateTime` and `DateTimeRaw` values should either both be null, or both be non-null. `DateTimeRaw` is just the original string representation which has been parsed for `DateTime`. If you're looking at an event with a `Date` value, I wouldn't expect `DateTimeRaw` to be non-null. Basically an event *either* has a date *or* a date/time, but never both.

Comment: @Neha: As for "Now i am not sure why this is happening" - for exactly the reason that my answer explains; because your debugger is using the default culture (ar-SA) which includes a Um Al Qura calendar.

Comment: I have inserted debug image in original question for your reference.  DateTime and DateTimeRaw both are NOT null as expected.

Comment: @Neha: In the image you've included in the question, they both *are* null... I don't understand what's left to answer, to be honest. I've explained how you should handle the data (parsing using the invariant culture, and parsing either Date or DateTimeRaw depending on which is non-null), and why it's showing up in an unexpected way in the debugger.